# Windows security thinks whatever I do with `open` is malware

Tags: python, file, windows-firewall

I use `open` command in python multiple times but when I compile it (using pyinstaller) and run it, Windows security just deletes my program away.

I didn't had any idea on fixing it, my best solution was just to avoid using `open` command or run it in admissistor (sorry if I got wrong spelling). I believe that there is better way of doing this.

Comment: The security tools are proprietary and the IOCs they use are (deliberately) undocumented, so questions about them aren't amenable to canonical answers. That said, it's pretty obvious why this would smell like likely malware activity. You might try getting a code-signing certificate and signing your payload, though even that's not a sure thing (since the call isn't being made directly by the signed binary but by something it unpacked and ran). To a significant extent, that's what you sign up for when you use an ugly hack like pyinstaller.

Comment: (To be clear, I'd call every one of pyinstaller's competitors just as much an ugly hack; to get out of ugly-hack space you need to use a real compiled language -- consider switching from CPython to IronPython so you can generate native CLR executables; a signed executable created by IronPython is more likely to be treated well than a signed executable from pyinstaller)

Comment: (not that IronPython is a proper compiled language, but it doesn't require the awful "unpack files into a temporary directory then run them" hack)